# Group by and aggregate the columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe.

```
    org_id          org_name        category                      org_status created_on  modified_on     location_id    loc_status  street_x    city          country
0   ORG-100023310   advanceCOR GmbH Industry,Pharmaceutical company ACTIVE  2016-10-18T15:38:34.322+02:00   2022-11-02T08:23:13.989+01:00   LOC-100052061   ACTIVE  Fraunhoferstrasse 9a, Martinsried   Planegg Germany
1   ORG-100023310   advanceCOR GmbH Industry,Pharmaceutical company ACTIVE  2016-10-18T15:38:34.322+02:00   2022-11-02T08:23:13.989+01:00   LOC-100032442   ACTIVE  Lochhamer Strasse 29a, Martinsried  Planegg Germany
```

I am trying to group this dataframe by the `org_id` column, and get all the unique values separated by ' | ' in the final dataframe.

The expected output is:

```
    org_id          org_name        category                      org_status created_on  modified_on     location_id    loc_status  street_x    city          country
0   ORG-100023310   advanceCOR GmbH Industry,Pharmaceutical company ACTIVE  2016-10-18T15:38:34.322+02:00   2022-11-02T08:23:13.989+01:00   LOC-100052061 | LOC-100032442   ACTIVE  Fraunhoferstrasse 9a, Martinsried | Lochhamer Strasse 29a, Martinsried  Planegg Germany
```

I have tried the following, but it produces an error.

```
join_unique = lambda x: '|'.join(x.unique())
df2 = df.groupby(['org_id'], as_index=False).agg(join_unique)
```

Error:

```
FutureWarning: ['loc_status', 'street_x', 'city', 'country'] did not aggregate successfully. If any error is raised this will raise in a future version of pandas. Drop these columns/ops to avoid this warning.
  df2 = df.groupby(['org_id'], as_index=False).agg(join_unique)
```

How can I get the desired output? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: can you plz provide the call where your df is created? makes it easier to try out for us

Answer (score 4):

IIUC convert values to strings:

```
join_unique = lambda x: '|'.join(x.unique().astype(str))
```

Or remove missing values and convert to strings:

```
join_unique = lambda x: '|'.join(x.dropna().astype(str).unique())
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have to be more specific column wise you can do this:

```
data = {
    'id': ['1', '1'],
    'col2': ['ciao', 'ciao1']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


grouped_df = df.groupby('id').agg({
    'col2': ' | '.join
}).reset_index()
```

result:

```
    id  col2
0   1   ciao | ciao1
```